# generating bent function from a bent bent function

Tags: finite-fields, cryptography

> Let $f:\mathbb{Z}_2^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ be a bent function (i.e. the Walsh transform of $f$ is $\mathcal{W}_{f}(a)=\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n}(-1)^{f(x)+a\cdot x}=\pm2^{n/2}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$). Prove that $g(x)=f(Ax+b)$ is also a bent function where $A$ is an invertible $n\times n $ matrix over $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$.

Since $A$ is invertible we can write the Walsh transform of $g$ as
$$\mathcal{W}_{g}(a)=(-1)^d\sum_{y \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n}(-1)^{f(y)+c\cdot (By)}$$
for some $B$ and $c, d$ associated to $A$ and $a$. I'm not sure how to proceed?

Comment: So $W_g(a)=(-1)^cW_f(bB)$, no?

Comment: @Mindlack the form is slightly different (we have $c \cdot By$ instead of $c \cdot y$).

Comment: Jason, if we think of $a$ as a row vector and $x$ as a column vector, then $a\cdot x$ is their matrix product $ax$. Implying that $c\cdot By=(cB)\cdot y$. If you think of both of both of them as column vectors, then $a\cdot x=a^Tx$ as a matrix product. Implying the rule $c\cdot By=(B^Tc)\cdot y$.